# How to create a template instantiation for an abstract baseclass?

Tags: c++, templates, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `Primitive`, which has some pure abstract functions.

Then i have a tree implementation with templates:

```
template<typename PrimitiveT>
class PrimitiveTree {
    ...
}
// explicit instantiation
template class PrimitiveTree<Project::Primitive>; // abstract
template class PrimitiveTree<SimpleTrianglePrimitive>; // implementation
```

which is used in another file as

```
PrimitiveTree<Primitive> *ptree;
```

With this code I get `error C2259: 'Project::Primitive': cannot instantiate abstract class`. When I remove the instantiation of the abstract class, I get linker errors that the corresponding symbol for `PrimitiveTree<Primitive>` is not found in the object file.

A similiar class with the methods inside the header file doesn't have these problems, when used with `Primitive` as template argument.

How do i need to instantiate the template class, such that the neccessary symbols are added to the object file, even when the template argument is an abstract class?

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to mix dynamic polymorphism with templates. Think twice.

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear how the template parameter `PrimitiveT` is used by the (specialisations of the) class template `PrimitiveTree`.

Comment: @Walter there is a magic tag `[mcve]` for [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the template `PrimitiveTree<PrimitiveT>` does not rely on `PrimitiveT` (the template parameter) being instantiable - in other words, not being abstract.   One property of an abstract class is that it cannot be instantiated.

This means your `PrimitiveTree` template must only work with pointers or references to `PrimitiveT`, and never instantiate an actual instance `PrimitiveT` in any way.   This means it is not possible to declare `PrimitiveT` as a data member (static or non-static).   It is not possible to pass a `PrimitiveT` by value.   It is also not possible dynamically create any instances with a `new` expression (e.g. `some_pointer = new PrimitiveT[5]`)  since a `new` expression relies on the type being instantiable (i.e. not abstract).

Everywhere where `PrimitiveT` is used must be either a reference or a pointer.  Defining or declaring a pointer or reference to `PrimitiveT`, or passing a reference/pointer as a function argument does not rely on `PrimitiveT` being instantiable.

If you write ANY code for `PrimitiveTree` that relies on `PrimitiveT` being instantiated, then the implementation cannot instantiate the template.

The "similar class" in another header file probably does not rely on `Primitive` being instantiable, since it follows guidelines like the above.